# Existence of extension from a subspace to whole space

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions, isometry

For any $x \in X$, define the set $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{span \{ \delta_x : x \in X \}}$ where $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f \in$ $Lip_0(X)$.

The set Lip$_0(X)$ is the set of all real-valued Lipschitz functions which vanish at $0$.

Note that $\delta_x$ is an evaluation functional on Lip$_0(X)$.

Define $\| \mu \|_{\mathcal{F}} = \sup_{\| f \|_{Lip}\leq1}{\int f d\mu}$.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $i : X \rightarrow Y$ is the
>   canonical embedding, then $\hat{i} : \mathcal{F}(X) \rightarrow
> > \mathcal{F}(Y)$ is an isometric embedding.

Proof: Suppose $\mu$ is a finitely supported measure on $X$. Choose $f \in Lip_0(X)$ with $\int f d\mu = \| u \| _{\mathcal{F}(X)}$, and $\| f \|_{Lip}=1$. Then $f$ has an extension to $g \in Lip_0(Y)$ with $\| g \|_{Lip}=1$. It follows that $\| \hat{i} \mu \|_{\mathcal{F}(Y)} = \| \mu \|_{\mathcal{F}(X)}$

The statement and proof is [Lemma $2.3$](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf).

Question:

$(1)$ Why there exists $f \in Lip_0(X)$ such that $\int f d\mu = \| u \| _{\mathcal{F}(X)}$, and $\| f \|_{Lip}=1$?

$(2)$ Why $f$ has an extension? Is it because $X$ is isometrically embedded into $Y$?

Comment: For 1: that is the definition of the norm on $Lip_0(X)$ through duality. For the second, if a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz and $X$ is closed then there is an extension to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not affect the Lipschitz constant, $f(x) = \inf_{y \in X} f(y) + K d(x,y)$ where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$ will do.

Comment: The norm on $Lip_0(X)$ through duality is $\| \mu \|_{\mathcal{F}}$? Why is $X$ closed?